# 3 gimbal gyroscope stability

Tags: angular-momentum, gyroscopes

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere but I´d rather put my trust in a dedicated community before youtube or wikipedia.

Once the rotor/flywheel is up to speed the rotation and centrifugal force mean the gyroscope can be moved, angled, and turned through all degrees but the spinning rotor will maintain or at least try to maintain its current axis (the less friction in the working parts, the less nutation should occur).

My question:

If I start my gyroscope and set it parallel to the floor (on a table) and I am not at the North or South Pole why over the period of 1 Earth revolution does the rotor stay parallel to the surface? 
If I understand correctly the rotor should maintain or try to maintain it´s original orientation which means every 6 hours the rotor (at the equator) should go, in relation to the Earths surface, parallel, perpendicular, parallel, perpendicular.

I don´t have a phd in Physics, please be gentle!

EDIT: By parallel to the floor or surface I mean the plane of the rotor is parallel to the surface as shown in my cave painting [image: gyro setup]

Comment: You need to specify your conditions a little more clearly. I assume from the question you have a gimbal gyroscope; but when you say "parallel to the floor", what is the direction of the axis of motion? It matters whether you point it along the North-South line (in which case it continues to point that way) or East-West (in which case it will appear to "tumble" every six hours as you described). If you constrain it to rotate in a horizontal plane, it will end up pointing at True North (the principle of the gyro compass...). So - please clarify.

Comment: How do you know that the rotor will stay parallel to the surface? Also a lot of gyroscope have too much internal friction that they will not spin for an entire day.

Comment: Because this it what happens in aircraft, helicopters and supposedly spaceships too, if gyroscopes didn´t behave in this way (Rigidity in space) my assumption is they would be useless in their current application (flying on intruments due to bad weather etc)

Comment: Aircraft don't have unconstrained gyros.  Aircraft gyros have parts that keep it righted with respect to local gravity over long periods.  http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14657/if-i-fly-a-balanced-turn-long-enough-will-the-ai-show-im-level

Comment: @BowlOfRed could you please cite some facts regarding that statement? What parts do they use? and how do said parts work?

Comment: @GeoffDutton, did you check the link in my earlier comment?  One of the answers shows how an angle between local acceleration (down) and the gyro axis opens air vents that cause a precession that erects the gyro.  The AI gyro gives information about short-term deviations.  It is not accurate over a long period of time.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Yes, thank you! I had been looking at Patents and designs but had yet to find a decent description/figure of the mechanism.

Comment: however that is not a 3 gimball mechanism, it is an erected mechanism to  show the attitude of the airplane, the instrumental horizon is the Gyro I am reffering to. (Apologies I thought I had made this comment months ago)